# Event for first load of a view controller in a UINavigationController?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

When my view controller is first presented, I want it to potentially update a cache that provides the data for that view. However, when the user taps the back button from a deeper view controller to return to this view controller, I don't want to update the cache again.

Which event should I be using?

- in `init`, I don't have all the parameters I need yet.
- `viewWillAppear` will be fired every time the view will appear.
- `viewDidLoad` will be fired every time the view has been loaded from the nib, which I believe could happen a second time if there's a memory warning. (Or is this wrong?) Since this is **not** a memory resident cache, it seems the wrong place to handle this.
- having the caller call something extra is inelegant, if there's a built-in way to handle this.

To clarify, this is not a memory resident cache. This is parsing an XML file to binary. The binary is loaded and unloaded in `viewDidLoad` and `viewDidUnload`. This is a prerequisite for that step, making sure the binary is up-to-date prior to it being loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `init` may work, but I would recommend a simple subclass of `UINavigationController`.  Create a new method called `setRootTableViewController:(UITableViewController *)controller`, or something like it.  In the method implementation call this:

```
[controller.tableView reloadData];
[self pushViewController:controller animated:NO];
```

`reloadData` will call all of your delegate and data source methods, and use them to update the table.  If you want a special method call on your table view controller instead, you could change the method declaration to `setRootTableViewController:(CustomTableViewController *)controller` (or whatever your custom table controller is called), and replace the `reloadData` line with one that calls that method.

Then, in your app delegate, instead of creating a `UINavigationController` and adding your custom view controller, create one of these, and call this method to add the first view.

However, if you are using a nib to set the `rootViewController`, you can just override `initWithRootViewController:(UIViewController *)controller`, as I imagine that is what the nib will call to set the first view in the stack:

```
- (id)initWithRootViewController:(UIViewController *)rootViewController {
  if ((self = [super init])) {
    [(CustomController *)rootViewController doSomethingSpecial];
    [self pushViewController:rootViewController];
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: also in a 4.0+ environment, the app could go into the background for several hours before coming back to the foreground, you will likely want to notice that and reload your cache - perhaps you should set a timestamp when you reload it and base your decision on that